# Может ли компилятор выводить код в не встроенную консоль?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я хочу, чтобы при использовании компилятора, когда я нажимаю на кнопку запуска кода, открывалась консоль и исполнялся код там, это возможно?

Я использую IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2.

Comment: Приложение выводит данные и считывает их не из консоли а из стандартных потоков ввода-вывода. Назначьте свои потоки ввода-вывода и радуйтесь.

Comment: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000162270-How-to-launch-console-app-in-external-window- ?

Comment: Но что-то мне подсказывает что вы хотели совершенно чего-то иного, но не смогли это сформулировать

Comment: @tym32167, похоже на ответ. Может оформите?

Comment: @МихаилРебров вопрос про java, а там c# - я не уверен, что для java есть конпка, а проверить не могу сейчас

Comment: @tym32167, с ходу не нашел ничего подобного той галочки в идее. И наоборот в багтрекере jetbrains нашел все еще открытый feature request, описывающий данную возможность.https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98471/

Comment: Хотя с другой стороны в ИДЕЕ есть настройка, в которой можно настроить терминал по умолчанию. Я могу поставить и bash, и zsh, и fish... другое дело, что это все будет во вкладке идеи запущено

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIi5f.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT100.png